# Azure key vault - add access policy for deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I have an app with 2 slots. I have stored connection strings in the key vault. I have enabled MSI on the app and 2 slots. Also, within the vault's access policy, I have added the app (production slot). However I am not able to add the slots to the access policy. E.g. My app's name is XYZ20180706 and the slots are XYZ20180706/dev and XYZ20180706/test. But when I type in XYZ20180706/dev or XYZ20180706-dev in the service principal, it is not found.

How do I create an access policy for a deployment slot?

Just having it enabled on the main slot is not enough. I currently get access denied (to vault) if I deploy the app to the dev slot and run it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AFAIK, we could access it after enabling [`MSI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) for `deployment slot`, you could check my test steps.

1.I have two slots, then I enable MSI of both of them in the portal.

[image]

[image]

2. You could check them in the **Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications** in the portal, refer to the screenshot.

   **Note**: You should specify the `Application Type` option with `All Applications` when you are searching.

[image]

3.Add **Add access policy** in the azure keyvault, you could find the slots in the principle (hover your cursor over it).

[image]

Comment: Using the ApplicationId worked for me. Otherwise, the development slot did not show up when I appended -development at the end of the app service name.

Comment: "Managed service identity" has been renamed to "Identity". Also the slot could take some minutes before appearing in "Add access policy" section (printsceen 3).

Comment: Is there any way to do above steps using yaml? I'm in the same exact situation where i would like to integrate this configuration as part of CI CD pipeline instead of manually enabling the identity and add access policy for the deployment slot.

Answer (score 6):

On the key vault "Add access policy" section (printsceen 3 from Joy Wang), when you selecting the principal type this: YourWebAppName/slots/YourDeploymentSlotName

After you type the entire string the autocomplete check will be green and you can select the principal from the list.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only way I was able to find my slot when adding a new access policy. It's amazing how poorly this feature is documented by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to provide keyvault access to deployment slots.

```
1.Select webapp(deployment slot) go to settings->identity->enable the status
2.go to keyvault -> access policies -> create-> select the required policies -> 
  in principle tab type following string <app-name>/slots/<deployment 
  slot(eg: staging)>

Hit like if you find this helpful.
```